# How to relate indexes of multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have this 2D array of basically terms and classes:

```
const content = [
  ['Spring 2017', 'Spring 2018', 'Spring 2019', 'Spring 2020'],
  ['Calc 1', 'Calc 2', 'Economics 1', 'Psychology 1'],
  ['Summer 2017', 'Summer 2018', 'Summer 2019', 'Summer 2020'],
  ['Swimming', 'English 1', 'History 1', 'Cooking 1']
]
```

I know how to loop through the main array and the sub arrays, but I want to relate the term with the class, so for example:

Spring 2017 - Calc 1

Spring 2018 - Calc 2

Spring 2019 - Economics 1

Spring 2020 - Psychology 1

I'm well aware that the data isn't structured very well. I feel like I've hit a wall with this.

Comment: and what are you trying to do?  collect them into an array of key/value objects like [{term: 'Spring', name: 'Calc'}]?  Or one key/value object {"Spring":"Calc"}?  Or list of arrays [ ['Spring','Calc'] ]?

Comment: I'm guessing I'd want something like [{term: 'Spring', name: 'Calc'}]

Comment: Depends on what you want to do.  If terms are unique and your code will be looking up class by term, you'd use the second one.  Sometimes a list of arrays is more convenient or fits iteration logic better.  There's a million and one ways to skin a cat and get usable meat out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the outer area two at a time. Then, iterate over the inner ones, and save the semester in the first array with the corresponding course in the second array in a `JSON` object as key-value pairs. You need to make sure that the length of the outer array is even, and that of the inner arrays are equal. I am assuming that semesters are unique, otherwise, you need to store them as objects in an array.

```js
const content = [
  ['Spring 2017', 'Spring 2018', 'Spring 2019', 'Spring 2020'],
  ['Calc 1', 'Calc 2', 'Economics 1', 'Psychology 1'],
  ['Summer 2017', 'Summer 2018', 'Summer 2019', 'Summer 2020'],
  ['Swimming', 'English 1', 'History 1', 'Cooking 1']
];
let coursesPerSemester = {};
if(content.length%2==0){
     for(let i = 0; i < content.length; i+=2){
          let semesters = content[i];
          if(content[i+1].length == semesters.length){
               for(let j = 0; j < semesters.length; j++){
                    coursesPerSemester[semesters[j]] = content[i+1][j];
               }
          }
     }
console.log(coursesPerSemester);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for loop processing 2 sets of arrays at once.  Assumes that sets of arrays are same length.

```js
const content = [
  ['Spring 2017', 'Spring 2018', 'Spring 2019', 'Spring 2020'],
  ['Calc 1', 'Calc 2', 'Economics 1', 'Psychology 1'],
  ['Summer 2017', 'Summer 2018', 'Summer 2019', 'Summer 2020','x'],
  ['Swimming', 'English 1', 'History 1', 'Cooking 1','y']
]

const res = []
for(let i = 0; i < content.length; i+=2)
for(let j = 0; j < content[i].length; j++) 
res.push({term: content[i][j], name: content[i+1][j]})

console.log(res)
```